# Hazelcast Outofmemory

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, hazelcast

Hazelcast Queue data structure is being used to exchanges messages in a producer consumer mode. There are 5 queues all of them with max-size=50 in hazelcast.xml. Producer gets blocked as expected while posting messages when the queue size reaches the max-size value. Tried using hazlcast in both embedded and client server mode. In both cases, after 15 minutes of operation, application becomes unresponsive. In embedded mode, hazelcast healthmonitor logs show the following

> Oct 09, 2017 2:13:45 PM
>   com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor INFO:
>   [127.0.0.1]:5702 [hj-12840-dev] [3.8.1] processors=4,
>   physical.memory.total=15.7G, physical.memory.free=8.2G,
>   swap.space.total=2.0G, swap.space.free=2.0G,
>   **heap.memory.used=2.2G**, **heap.memory.free=1.1M**, heap.memory.total=2.2G, heap.memory.max=2.2G,
>   heap.memory.used/total=99.95%, **heap.memory.used/max=99.95%**,
>   minor.gc.count=218, minor.gc.time=50371ms, **major.gc.count=176**,
>   major.gc.time=559748ms, load.process=0.33%, load.system=0.27%,
>   load.systemAverage=100.00%, thread.count=115, thread.peakCount=117,
>   cluster.timeDiff=-4670, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0,
>   executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0,
>   executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0,
>   executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0,
>   executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=74875,
>   executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0,
>   executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0,
>   operations.running.count=0,
>   operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%,
>   operations.pending.invocations.count=2, proxy.count=0,
>   clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=1,
>   client.connection.count=0, connection.count=1

Data is pushed in queues only and consumer is using the poll() method to get messages from queue. Using an external application, verified the remainingCapacity of queues which reports that queued messages are getting processed and are removed from queue as expected. Queue endpoints are configured as follows

```
hazelcast:seda:default?pollTimeout=1000&concurrentConsumers=5&transferExchange=false&transacted=false&hazelcastInstance=#hazelcastInstance
```

**Hazelcast Version: 3.8.1**. Used with Camel Hazelcast component (version 2.19) along with Spring boot (1.5.3.RELEASE).

Has anyone experienced a similar problem before? Anything I may be missing here?

Comment: How big are the items ? Can you post a heapdump of biggest objects ?

Comment: My bad. After profiling it appears to be an issue with one of the third party library API's being used. Issue is not related to Hazelcast.